# Error while importing Boost 1.61.0 to C++ project

Tags: c++, boost, clion

I tried to import Boost 1.61.0 (downloaded from [SourceForge - Boost 1.61.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.61.0/) as .7z), but failed.

Console:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Marczak\.CLion2016.2\system\cmake\generated\WsServer-e351c9f9\e351c9f9\Debug --target WsServer -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable WsServer.exe
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'WsServer.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [WsServer.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [WsServer] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'WsServer' failed
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(WsServer)

set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)

find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(WsServer ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

If I do `find_package(Boost 1.61.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)` I get:

```
Error: Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.61.0
Boost include path: C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0
Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
        boost_system         boost_filesystem
No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
```

I tried to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` on, but it failed too. I use CLion 2016.2.

**UPDATE:** I tried older versions too. Same error. What's inside the .7z:

[image: .7z file]

In other topics I see `lib` folder. But here I don't see it. What I should put in `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`?

**UPDATE 2:** Installed binary from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.61.0/ . I noticed there's new folder: `lib64-msvc-14.0`. It contains many .dll and .lib files, e.g. `boost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_61.dll`.

Boost.org says:

> If you plan to use your tools from the Windows command prompt, you're in the right place. If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually running on a POSIX platform and should follow the instructions for getting started on Unix variants. Other command shells, such as MinGW's MSYS, **are not supported—they may or may not work**.

I'll try using Cygwin.

Comment: Did you compile boost with whatever compiler you are using here? Sounds like you just extracted the source code at `C:/Users/Marczak/boost_1_61_0`

Comment: @drescherjm No. I'm new in C++.  How to compile it?

Comment: Maybe a boost binary download for mingw would be better for you. With that said I am not sure what compiler / toolkit `CLion` is using under windows. Is it mingw/gcc??

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, it is.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak you might want to add the clion and mingw tags, because they quite centrally describe your problem, don't they?

Comment: @MarcusMüller What tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to C++, I suggest you to download MinGW distribution maintained by Stephan T. Lavavej (Microsoft C++ developer): https://nuwen.net/mingw.html. It, among other tools and libraries, contains pre-built boost binaries. Unpack it and specify the path to it via `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains`.

After that you should be able to compile the program with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(WsServer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(WsServer ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(WsServer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Don't forget to drop CMake cache as `find_packages` doesn't update successful results due to performance reasons (in CLion it can be done via `Cmake toolbar | Cache | red arrows icon`).

Some additional remarks:

- `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` is not meant to be set manually, it is set by running `find_package(Boost)`, which uses `BOOST_ROOT` or `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR + BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, you should set those if required. You don't have to do it with the MinGW distro I've linked because it already has boost includes and libraries in accessible locations.
- You can check that the paths to libraries are correct by looking at `Boost_*` variables in CMake cache.
- `libs` directory inside boost sources is unrelated to the problem, it doesn't conitain any binaries
- You've downloaded boost binaries built with Visual Studio toolchain, not MinGW, so they are incompatible with your setup. If you don't want to use MinGW package I've linked, you have to either find boost binaries built with correct MinGW version or build it yourself.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much.